# UK Standard Visitor Visa refusal due to unclear sponsorship - how to reapply?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, moroccan-citizens, proof-of-accommodation

I applied for a UK general visitor visa, and after a month, I found out that my visa got rejected for these reasons:
my host family sent me a invitation letter, but we haven't mentioned how we know each other. They also said I gave no proof that I would come back to my home town.

How Am I supposed to prove it? How to prove that strong ties to my home country? I'm a university student, and I'm only allowed to get a documents that shows my summer holiday, and other one that proves I'm a student.

This is the decision:

> You state that you intend to travel to the UK for a period of 3 weeks to visit friends. I note that you have provided copies of your sponsor's passports and documents relating to their circumstances in the UK as evidence of this. However, there is no indication in the documents whom you will be travelling to Tunbridge Wells with; given that you have never previously travelled to the UK, I consider this particularly relevant. This casts doubts on the credibility of your application and on your intentions in visiting the UK.
>
> In the light of the above, I am not satisfied that you are genuinely seeking entry as a visitor for a limited period as stated by you, not exceeding 6 months, or that you intend to leave the UK at the end of this period.
>
> I have therefore refused your application because I am not satisfied, on the balance of probabilities, that you meet all of the requirements of the relevant Paragraph of the UK immigration Rules.

I submitted my parents bank statements and all their financial, their financial support letter that proves they will fund my trip, a document from my university that proves I'm a student, an invitation letter from my british friends with all their financial details, passport copies and accommodation details , a music festival ticket, my marital status document, and my previous passport with previous Schengen visas.

Comment: What nationality are you?

Comment: I'm moroccan @DJClayworth

Comment: What documents did you submit on the last application? Did you submit the stuff that proves you're a student?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the exact text about 'mentioned how we know each other'? It's the relevant paragraphs in your refusal notice.  Without, it's 'unclear what you're asking'.  Close voting.

Comment: I've submitted my parents bank statements and all their financial ,their financial support letter that proves they will fund my trip,a document from my university that proves I'm a student, an invitation letter from my british friends with all their financial details , passport copies and accommodation details ,a   music festival ticket , my marital status document, and my previous passport with previous Schengen visas. @DJClayworth

Comment: @GayotFow I've edited it.

Comment: Close vote retracted in favour of seeing their formulae added to the question

Comment: @GayotFow am I correct in reading the refusal as implying that the everlasting officer assumes that the applicant is not capable to travel alone between the point of entry and Tunbridge Wells?

Comment: @phoog, it does, but more that the ECO thinks the applicant is lying. Something went terribly wrong during the evaluation. These are *extremely* rare. Read the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the formulae in your refusal notice, this is a [captious](http://onelook.com/?w=captious&ls=a&loc=home_ac_captious) refusal.  They are rarely issued.

What this *generally* means is that they found something objectionable (or several things), but there was no refusal formulae they could use (either for security reasons or for reasons related to your personal circumstances).

It could also be that something flagged up on your hosts, but that's less likely.  Have your hosts sponsored previously?  Do you know your hosts solely through the net? Do they have a clean record? Stuff like that.

Whatever it is, you'll need to fix it before applying again.  The fastest way is to instruct a fee earning member of the [Law Society](http://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/) to represent your next application.  You'll need to provide them with copies of EVERYTHING you submitted (I'm guessing the cost will be about GBP 900+, more for the very best, but it's a **guess only**). Nobody will be able to give a precise estimate without assessing the complexity of your case, and that means getting all your stuff spread out on a table and looking at it carefully.

Secondarily, you can spend a few years getting lots of [peripatetic](http://onelook.com/?w=peripatetic&ls=a&loc=home_ac_peripat) experience in places like the USA, Canada, or Schengen zone.  It takes a lot longer, but they love to see that kind of thing and it almost always guarantees success.

It wouldn't be advisable to make a fresh application right away because if you send the same stuff or even change it, they will refuse again.  And if your new stuff contradicts your old stuff (even a little itty-bitty bit), matters will be worse.